# ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC app works locally but doesn't when deployed to IIS & results in Http error 500

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, iis, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC app which runs perfectly fine locally. I then use Web Deploy and publish the app 'successfully' to IIS.

Although the website will just show the browser's generic http 500 error (it will prompt a Windows log-in first, as intended, although I believe this is unrelated to the issue).

[image: HTTP 500 ERROR]

Upon further inspection of the server's event viewer, it appears to be throwing this error:

> Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched: /Views/Admin/Index.cshtml /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml /Pages/Shared/Index.cshtml

For some more context the code I was pushing is ASP.NET Core 6, while the old version that is there was using ASP.NET Core 5. I *have* installed the .NET Core 6 Hosting Bundle as well.

I have tried using precompiled views by adding following property to the project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>true</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This didn't change any behavior.

I'm thinking it's something to do with the configuration of IIS perhaps? Or how I am deploying?

Here is my web deploy settings: (Details removed)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>https://example.url.ca:443/</SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <ProjectGuid>12345a12-a123-1aaa-a123-12356a1aa1aa</ProjectGuid>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
    <MSDeployServiceURL>https://example:1234/msdeploy.axd</MSDeployServiceURL>
    <DeployIisAppPath>ExampleMVC</DeployIisAppPath>
    <RemoteSitePhysicalPath />
    <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>False</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
    <MSDeployPublishMethod>WMSVC</MSDeployPublishMethod>
    <EnableMSDeployBackup>True</EnableMSDeployBackup>
    <EnableMsDeployAppOffline>True</EnableMsDeployAppOffline>
    <UserName>EXAMPLE\EX123</UserName>
    <_SavePWD>True</_SavePWD>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AllowUntrustedCertificate>True</AllowUntrustedCertificate>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using Visual Studio 2019 to publish the app. I downloaded and installed Visual Studio 2022 and published it (without doing anything else), and that fixed my issue. I've heard that Visual Studio 2019 doesn't really support .NET Core 6.0

Comment: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0 You can read that .NET 6 is exclusively on VS2022 from the download page.